# How to modify the privilege level of a running Linux service?

Tags: linux

I start a Linux Service as a Root user. Once the Service starts running, I'd like to change the User to a Non-privileged user (for eg., 'testuser')
Please advise on how to perform the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @drewbenn. But my Service is basically a pre-built Java application, so I can't programatically change the user/privilege (secondly, java doesn't seem to support setuid/getuid). I was looking at a command-line option to change the User of the service after the service is started with Root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

- Under a systemd based you have to specify the directives User= and Group= in the [Service] section of the unit file  /etc/systemd/system/.service
- Under Init.d based os : edit /etc/rc.d/init.d/ by adding 'chuid' to  'start-stop-daemon --chuid '